# Avoid scientific notation parsing

Tags: java, parsing

I have to find out if a string is a number or not.
I did it using Float.parseFloat(), managing the exception in case of non number.

Everything is ok except when the string is something like "113f" (an agency code in my project) that Java understand as a number with scientific notation.

Is there a way to "disable" the scientific notation to be parsed ?

Comment: What is your definition of valid numbers then? Is Hex-Notation as "0xFFAA" considered a number? Perhaps this would actually be a decent case for regex (and I am hesitant to suggest using it, usually).

Comment: Hi Fildor, only a number with a "normal" notation has to be considered valid (no hex, no scientific, ...)

Comment: What about decimal-separator and grouping separators? Are they Culture-Dependent? Example: de-DE => "1.234,56" de-CH=> "1'234.56" en-US => "1,234.56" ...

Comment: I was trying to avoid regex :( I was wondering if exist something built-in in Java or in some external jars (e.g. apache commons,..)

Comment: Believe me, I avoid regex whenever I can. If not for my own sanity then for the sake of my fellow devs. But here you seem to have a pretty narrow definition of the allowed format. So before misusing something for your validation that does not meet your requirements, I'd give it a try.